How to validate user access to premium features in a NestJS application following Clean Architecture principles?
I'm implementing a NestJS application following Clean Architecture principles. I want to validate if a user has access to a premium feature.
Here's my current architecture:
Controller (Application Layer):
Validates user authentication using decorators.
Prepares input for the use case by creating a use case adapter.
Use Case Adapter: Performs basic validation on the input.
Use Case: Contains the business logic.
My goal:
I want to add validation to check if the user has access to a premium feature. Ideally, this validation should not clutter the controller or the use case with additional logic.
What I have considered:
Creating a custom decorator and using it in the controller for business rule validation.
Implementing a guard to handle the validation logic and using a service to encapsulate the actual validation checks.
eg: @PremiumFeature('can-create-more-than-10-posts')
But I think this will break the clean-architecture principles, As I am doing the business rule validation in the application layer.

In nest JS you need to guard your application at application layer. Imagine you have guard that checks for user access rights. You will have to use the guard in similar way like  @AccessRights({ module: Modules.MyModule, right: Rights.Modify }) where @AccessRights is guard implemented using CanActivate method using reflector  by setting access-rights metadata here.
Similarly you will have to do. The approach is correct. I cannot htink of any other way to do this
